# SQLAlchemy not updating record

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-wtforms

I'm not getting any errors, it just isn't updating the record. I am editing the User record and saving individual fields (I can't use `populate_obj()` because I am only updating a select few fields but after `db.session.commit()`, it still does not update the table.

```
@app.route("/user/edit/<int:user_id>", methods=["GET", "POST"])
@login_required
def edit_user(user_id):
    user = User.query.get_or_404(user_id)
    form = EditUserForm()
    form.username.data = user.username
    form.email.data = user.email
    form.first_name.data = user.first_name
    form.last_name.data = user.last_name
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        user.email = form.email.data
        user.first_name = form.first_name.data
        user.last_name = form.last_name.data
        db.session.commit()
        flash("Updated user '{}'".format(user.username))
        return redirect(url_for("user"))
    return render_template("user_edit_form.html", form=form, action="Edit", user_id=user_id)
```

It even redirects flashes the message that it updated the record but nothing is written to the mysql database by sqlachemy.

Adding `db.session.flush()` after `commit()` makes no difference, nor does adding user to the session prior to the commit (`db.session.add(user)`).

How do I update the record?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember, the code before the `if form.validate_on_submit` is still executed when a form is submitted-- and in that code you're overriding the form-data with data from the database.

Lets pretend that the user has changed their email from 'old@foo.com' to 'new@foo.com' on the submitted form-- this is the code that will execute if we fall down the form is valid branch:

```
user = User.query.get_or_404(user_id)
form = EditUserForm()
form.username.data = user.username
# at this point form.email.data would be 'new@foo.com' but....
form.email.data = user.email # we then override it with 'old@foo.com'
form.first_name.data = user.first_name
form.last_name.data = user.last_name
user.email = form.email.data # read 'old@foo.com' from the data (since we over-rode it above)
user.first_name = form.first_name.data
user.last_name = form.last_name.data
db.session.commit().
flash("Updated user '{}'".format(user.username))
return redirect(url_for("user"))
```

So the `new@foo.com` data gets destroyed before the form is even validated.  So when you update, you're just updating with the already-stored values.

Comment: OK that makes sense. I added a check if the request method was GET and only populate fields initially if so. Then I only validate on POST method. Seems to be working mostly fine now. Thanks!